# MVC 4: How do I pass the selected value DropDownList as a QueryString parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My View code is

```
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
   <td height="36" align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><strong>System</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td height="36">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CSNumber, new SelectList(ViewBag.System, "Value", "Text", Model.CSNumber), "--- All ---", new { @class = "box", id = "ddlSystem" })
    </td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
   <td height="36" align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"></td>
   <td height="36">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System = @Html.Value(**"ddlSystem"**)
         <a class="" href="~/jobs/Create?system=<<Currently Selected Value of **"ddlSystem"** up above>>" id="createLink" style="text-decoration: underline">NEW REQUEST</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

How do I pass currently selected ddlSystem dropdown value when the user clicks CREATE NEW REQUEST LINK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do with jQuery, something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#createLink").click(function () {
        var selectedValue = $('#ddlSystem option:selected').val();

        window.location = "@Url.Action("Create", "Jobs")?system=" + selectedValue;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write **JQuery** as shown below which actually sets the "href" attribute of your link. In this way the "href" will be updated when the dropdown value will be changed by the user.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function setBtnUrl() {
        $('#createLink').attr('href', '/jobs/Create?system=' + $("#ddlSystem").val());// here it update the URL based on selected value
    }
    $("#ddlSystem").change(function () {
        setBtnUrl();
    });
    setBtnUrl();// set the selected value on page load.

});
</script>
```